# how to call methods after a rest service serialises a JSON request in POJO?

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, serialization

MyPojo.java

```
public class MyPojo
{
    private String str1;
    private String str2;
    private String str3;

    //setters
    //getters
}
```

RestController

```
@RestController
public class MyController 
{
    public @ResponseBody
    String getDetails(@RequestBody MyPojo myPojo) 
    {

    }
}
```

jsonRequest

```
{
    "str1" : "value1",
    "str2" : "value2"
}
```

Now when I make the API call from postman and make a breakpoint in the first line in controller , i can see that RequestBody variable myPojo has been serialised and has values for two variables .
which works correctly for me.

Now I want some features like , where I can call a method , which takes the value from str1 and str2 and set str3 with value of str1 and str2 concatenated .

what I have tries
1 : made the POJO a component by @Component , but it initialises the value while context gets loaded and at that time , the object is empty

Is there a way I can assign the concatenated value to `str3` after the request has been received in the api?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@JsonGenerator` on your constructor to solve this problem:

```
@JsonGenerator
public MyPojo(@JsonProperty("str1") String str1, @JsonProperty("str2") String str2) {
    this.str1 = str1;
    this.str2 = str2;
    this.str3 = str1 + str2;
}
```

Jackson (the deserializer used by spring) will call this constructor if the `@JsonGenerator` annotation is present. The `@JsonProperty` annotations tells it in what order the values should be passed into the constructor.

If you really want to only concatenate `str1` and `str2` and save it as `str3` you might aswell initialize it lazily in its *getter*:

```
public String getStr3(){
    if(str3 == null){
        str3 = str1 + str2;
    }
    return str3;
}
```

Comment: no i have bit complex logic there so cant use  getter enhancement , can you share maven dependency for @JsonGenerator

Comment: @hussainakhtarWahid you can find the latest version [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core)